# Create a separate view for each primary menu based on URL aliases in drupal 7

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, uri

I have created a taxonomy menu in drupal 7. Let say the main menu has technology and market data.

1. Let say Technology has sub menu as security and security has test1 and hello as sub menus and so on.

   ```
   -Technology       URl: http://localhost/drupal/taxonomy/term/1
        -- Security    URL: http://localhost/drupal/taxonomy/term/2
            --Test     URL: http://localhost/drupal/taxonomy/term/3
            --Hello    URL: http://localhost/drupal/taxonomy/term/4
   ```
2. Market data also has the same hierarchy.
3. These are the values I have set while creating the view

   ```
       Format:

         Unformatted list | Settings

         Show:Content | Teaser

       FILTER CRITERIA
         Content: Published (Yes)

         Content: Type (= Article) 

         Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth) (or Technology, ...) | Settings

       PAGE SETTINGS

         Path:/taxonomy/term/%

         Menu:No menu

         Access:Permission | View published content 

       CONTEXTUAL FILTERS
         Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)
   ```

After creating this view I am able to see the view in all pages (Technology,Security,test1,Hello) I am able to display article as mention in point 1.

Now I replaced the url with automaic url aliases and the url it generate the following URL.

```
        -Technology       URl: http://localhost/drupal/technology
             -- Security    URL: http://localhost/drupal/technology/security
                  --Test     URL: http://localhost/drupal/security/test
                  --Hello    URL: http://localhost/drupal/security/Hello
```

Now I replaced the view with following settings

```
     Format:

   Unformatted list | Settings

   Show:Content | Teaser

FILTER CRITERIA
   Content: Published (Yes)

   Content: Type (= Article) 

   Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth) (or Technology, ...) | Settings

 PAGE SETTINGS

   Path:/technology/%

   Menu:No menu

   Access:Permission | View published content 

 CONTEXTUAL FILTERS
   Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)

Within  Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) has the following settings:

     WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS IN THE URL OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED
       Override title:    %1
     Specify validation criteria

      Validator

         Taxonomy Term

      Vocabularies

         Home Page Main Menu

      Filter value type

         Term name converted into ID

   I have selected the Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values also.
```

But the problem is I am not able to overwrite the taxonomy pages.

Can anyone help me what I have missed while creating the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this problem has to do with how path aliases are handled. When the url is set to a page alias, Drupal translates the url into its actual url `taxonomy/term/tid` before it seeks the content that is to be displayed, such as your view definition whose path is still an alias.  Since the view path doesn't match the URL, it is not selected to generate content.  If you want a descriptive URL to work with the view path, you cannot use the path aliases.

I have a similar problem where I have converted hundreds of hierarchical taxonomy terms into a menu system with aliases using taxonomy menu. The aliases show up fine when I select a menu item, and set the View definition to `Taxonomy/term/%` but the views, of course, display the base URL instead of the alias.  I have not explored a work-around yet.  If you find anything, please post it here on your question.